# Onclick Class Toggle Not Firing

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple class toggle for a number of different clickable elements on the page.

```
<script>
    const toggleActiveEls = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-active');

    function toggleActive() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    }

    toggleActiveEls.forEach(i => {
        i.addEventListener("click", toggleActive);
    });
</script>
```

I have a page with a large number of partials being loaded in. They take a while to load, and some of the partials contain buttons that should have the event listener, but I've not been able to get the event listener to apply to all of the partials. (Though it does seem to apply to some.)

I've tried delaying the code until all of the partials load, but that didn't seem to work.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        const toggleActiveEls = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-active');

        function toggleActive() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
        }

        toggleActiveEls.forEach(i => {
            i.addEventListener("click", toggleActive);
        });
    })
</script>
```

I'm a little baffled by what to do next. This seemed like an elegant solution, so I'm hoping it can be salvaged.

Comment: I think `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {}) ` would be more fitting in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will 100% fix your problem, but generally it's not a good idea to attach event listeners to a lot of items. Rather, you should do event delegation - attach one click listener on the parent DOM node and determine if you are clicking on an item inside your method.

Observe:

```js
let myList = document.getElementById('my-list')
myList.addEventListener('click', onClick)

function onClick (e) {
  var clickedItem = e.target
  
  for (let i = 0; i < myList.children.length; i++) {
    var listItem = myList.children[i]
    if (clickedItem === listItem) {
      listItem.classList.add('active')
    } else {
      listItem.classList.remove('active')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolar</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
  <li>Irem</li>
  <li>Lopsum</li>
</ul>
```

## EDIT

Nothing prevents you from attaching one listener on the outermost element (document.body) and then providing custom logic depending on what kind of element you clicked. That being said, this is not realistic, so it is up to you to find the highest parent where it makes sense to attach a single click listener.

Here is an example where I have more complicated DOM structure:

```js
let myContainer = document.getElementById('my-container')
myContainer.addEventListener('click', onClick)

// Get all the items I want to be clickable on the page
var allListItems = myContainer.getElementsByTagName('li')

function onClick (e) {
  let clickedItem = e.target

  // Notice how I am checking explicitly if I have clicked on LI
  // This logic will not run if I click on a <section>, <h2> or anything else
  if (clickedItem.nodeName === 'LI') {
    for (let i = 0; i < allListItems.length; i++) {
      let listItem = allListItems[i]
      if (listItem === clickedItem) {
        listItem.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        listItem.classList.remove('active')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-container">
  <h2>List #1</h2>
  <section>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolar</li>
    <li>Sit amet</li>
  </section>
  <h2>List #2</h2>
  <section>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolar</li>
    <li>Sit amet</li>
  </section>
  <h2>List #3</h2>
  <section>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolar</li>
    <li>Sit amet</li>
  </section>
</div>
```

The key part is `if (clickedItem.nodeName === 'LI') {}`, where I run my logic only if I have clicked on a list item. All other clicks on other elements will not be handled.

#### Edit II

While I check the `nodeName` property to determine if I should run my logic depending on the clicked node, you can check for anything that makes sense to you. You can check if the clicked item has a particular class applied using `if (clickedItem.contains('clickable-el') {}` or even some attribute like this:

HTML

```
<li data-clickable>Element</li>
```

JS

```
if (clickedItem.dataset.clickable) {}
```

Again, it's up to you to invent your own convention and follow it. You can read more on event delegations and its benefits [here](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: Thank you for the tip on not adding a bunch of event listeners.

When attaching it to the parent, does it need to be the direct parent? I'd like to attach it to just one DIV, rather than use a function for each parent.

Comment: Provided one more smaller update to make things clearer

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this out and will respond back if it answers the original question. Regardless, seeing this logic has been very helpful to me personally, so thank you.

Comment: I have what I suspect is a very stupid question with a broad answer, but here goes:

You say that "Nothing prevents you from attaching one listener on the outermost element (document.body) ...That being said, this is not realistic," Why is it not realistic to do?

Comment: The exact code presented didn't quite work for me, probably due to my error, but this answer directed me where I needed to go to find what I needed. Here's what I ended up with: 

`<!-- Toggles Active on all applicable elements -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

            if (event.target.matches('.toggle-active')) {
                event.target.classList.toggle('active');
            }

        }, false);
    </script>`

Comment: Hey, I am happy you fixed your problem. It is not realistic because it is not maintainable as your app grows. Imagine having 10 different UI widgets on a page - calendars, spreadsheet, galleries, etc. Imagine what nightmare would be to manage ALL clicks for them in a single event listener. In your example, attaching it to `document` works so it might be all you really need. But as applications grow and more UI is added you will want to have different event listeners for different sections. Again, no hard rules here, it really depends :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It's really helpful, and I can already see areas that won't be bound to the single listener, but this simple concept has already cleaned up a lot of unnecessary inline code from outside agencies, and has allowed me to control the animations in a single location. I appreciate your help!